# Setting a timer for a long period of time || React native & Firebase issue

Tags: firebase, react-native

Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.

```
(Saw setTimeout with duration 285987ms)
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:71:8 in console.warn
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:242:8 in setTimeout
* http://192.168.43.142:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:161047:29 in setTimeoutNonBlocking
* http://192.168.43.142:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:167896:28 in reportStats_
* [native code]:null in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:399:17 in callTimers
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue...

```
Navigate to your node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js file.

Look for the variable MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS

Change its value to 10000 * 1000

Save the changes (with auto format turned off) and re-build your app.
```

Found this answer on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97#issuecomment-485410026